# trying to display data in jade from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

trying to display data from mongoose schema to jade temaplate but it dosent work no matter what i try , so please help me and thanks .

first here is my book schema models/book.js

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const schema = mongoose.Schema

const BookSchema = new schema({
  title: String,
  author: String,
  isbn: Number,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
  description: String
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema)
```

and here is my controller for the book model

```
    const Book = require('../models/book')
const express = require('express')
router = express.Router()


router.route('/books')
  // Create a book
  .post( (req, res) => {
    const book = new Book()
    book.name = req.body.name

    book.save( (err) => {
      if (err)
        res.send(err)

      console.log('Book created! ')
    })
  })

  //get all books
  .get( (req, res) => {
    Book.find( (err, books) => {
      if (err)
        res.send(err)

      res.render('books', {title: 'books list'})
    })
  })




module.exports = router
```

and at last here is my jade template

```
    extends layout

block content
  if books
    each book in books
      h1 #{book.title}
```

Comment: As Ravi pointed out below, you need to send `books` in your `res.render` call for it to be available in your template. Rest is fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mistakes/modifications required in your code.

1. while finding, its better to give `{}` as first input.
2. When rendering the book template, you are using `books` variable to show list of books, but you are not sending it from the route. you need to send `books` in `res.render`.

Try this:

```
router.route('/books')
  // Create a book
  .post( (req, res) => { 
    const book = new Book()
    book.name = req.body.name

    book.save( (err) => {
        res.send(err)

      console.log('Book created! ')
    })
  })

  //get all books
  .get((req, res) => {
    Book.find({},(err, books) => { 
      if (err)
        res.send(err)

      res.render('books', {title: 'books list' , books : books})//need to send the books variable to the template.
    })
  })
```

Comment: Their use of arrow functions is correct. If you specify the `function` keyword, no need for the arrows.