# how to display data from mongodb to jade/pug, nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I am trying to achieve a simple get data (all years/distinct years) from mongodb and display it into a select dropdown table, as shown.

[image: pie]

I've searched and searched for solutions, but I either don't get it or it's not specific to what I need, written in what I am using. This link [trying to display data in jade from mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929034/trying-to-display-data-in-jade-from-mongodb) is probably the most specific to what I am wanting, for now. But even following the example, I still cannot get my variable countries passed to jade. Later, I plan on using the years in the list to use as variables to query mongodb, using ajax.

This is what I have so far, please tell me what I am doing wrong or why it is not working as intended.

Country.js (Model)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var countrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    year: { 
        type: Number, 
        required: true
    },
    nominalGDP: Number,
    ...
    ...
});

var Country = mongoose.model('Country', countrySchema);

//****outputs to console, all the data I have****
Country.find(function (err, countries){
  console.log(countries);
});

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = Country;
```

fetchCountries.js (Controller)

```
var Country = require('../models/country')
var express = require('express')
router = express.Router()


router.route('/')
.get( (req, res) => {
    Country.find({}, (err, countries) => {
      if (err)
        res.send(err)

      //***Does not output here***  
      console.log(countries);
      res.render('layout', {title: 'country list', countries: countries})
    });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var express, path, favicon, logger, cookieParser, ... routes such as /index 
and /template, var app = express();

//Set up mongoose connection
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://user, pass';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'images', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/template', template);


//var Country = require('../models/country');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  Country.find(function (err, countries){
    res.render('layout', {countries: countries});
  });    
});
module.exports = app;
```

layout.jade (view)

```
 ul List
        if countries
          each country in countries
            li #{country.year}
```

it's on localhost:3000/, where the '/' is the home page. I'm using Mongodb/mongoose, node js, expressjs, and jade/pug.

Edit: updated fetchCountries controller
Edit 2: added app.js and updated where console.log outputs (in model)

Comment: `countries` is not passed in the template context in `res.render` call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to display data in jade from mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929034/trying-to-display-data-in-jade-from-mongodb)

Comment: how would I pass it? res.render('layout', {title: 'country list', countries: countries})?
I did that but it still did not pass it

Comment: res.render('layout', {title: 'country list', countries: countries})
still didn't pass it
Edit: correct way to write it

Comment: We need error what you have got.

Comment: nothing, it's just the usual script, images, stylesheets, etc.

Comment: I've updated the fetchCountries.js controller in the post.

Comment: Replace `console.log(countries)` with  `console.log('countries: ', typeof countries, countries)`. Restart server, visit the route in browser, and check the terminal for where `countries: ` is logged

Comment: It didn't work inside the fetchCountries controller, but it was able to output to the console inside the country.js model. I will add my app.js code for a better understanding